# How can I set up an Authorized View using DDL?

Tags: google-bigquery

According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views), I should be able to create Authorized views using BigQuery's Data Definition Language (DDL):

---

### Creating authorized views

You can create an authorized view in BigQuery by:

- Using the GCP Console or the classic BigQuery web UI.
- Using the command line tool's bq mk command
- Calling the tables.insert API method
- **Submitting a CREATE VIEW Data Definition Language (DDL) statement**

---

I can't see how that's the case. There aren't any view options related to authorization. I see only [options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#view_option_list) are `labels`, `description`, `friendly_name`, and `expiration_timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `CREATE VIEW`s with DDL, but to set permissions you'll have to use the API or one of the documented methods:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views#granting_views_access_to_datasets

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know how to create authorized views via API/console, but I'm using getdbt.com, which uses DDL statements. It seems the docs are just plain wrong here. "You can create an authorized view in BigQuery by: - Submitting a CREATE VIEW Data Definition Language (DDL) statement"

Comment: Yeah, I see the issue. With my answer I just wanted to give you a confirmation that you can't currently set permissions with DDL.